# Login functionality is not working properly

Tags: asp.net

I have problems with a site. I restored a backup and now you can only login when you reload the page. It's also in .Net

> > If I click on login there is no event happening. Only when reloading page you can enter the site.

This is sample of login button code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" value="Email ID" onblur="if(this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email ID'; this.type='text';}" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Email ID') {this.value = ''; this.type='Email ID';}" runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" value="Password"  onblur="if(this.value == '') {this.value = 'Password'; this.type='text';}" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Password') {this.value = ''; this.type='Password';}" runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox>

<div  class="forgot my_modal_forgot_open" style="text-align: center;padding-bottom: 15px;">
  <a id="forgot" href="#" style="font-weight: bold;color: #5E013F;font-style: italic;font-size: 12px;">Forgot Password</a>
</div>

<asp:Button CssClass="yes" ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" 
     style="width: 100px;color:#fff;"  >
</asp:Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because there is no event handler for the `login` button click event and I am guessing that you have put the code inside the `Page_Load` event like this

```
if(IsPostBack)
{
   // your login code
}
```

So whenever you reload the page of press `F5` postback occurs and your code executes which ultimately do the login.

So you need to add the event handler for login button like this (Look at `OnClick`)

```
<asp:Button CssClass="yes" ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" style="width: 100px;color:#fff;"  ></asp:Button>
```

Now put the login code inside this event handler

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Your login code
}
```

Comment: Can I embed the event handler in the page or should I add in the Javascript file?

Comment: You can write this code in your code behind file. No need to add javascript file.